# Oracle 11g. Output data within seven days

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

There is `Transactions` table in Oracle 11g, like example:

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (id, sender_name, transaction_date, amount) AS
SELECT '1111', 'Alice', TIMESTAMP '2023-01-03 01:26:29', 700 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2222', 'Alice', TIMESTAMP '2023-01-05 04:26:29', 450 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '3333', 'Alice', TIMESTAMP '2023-01-08 18:26:29', 1000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '4444', 'Alice', TIMESTAMP '2023-01-09 04:26:29', 200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL

SELECT '6666', 'Betty', TIMESTAMP '2023-03-12 15:26:29', 845 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '7777', 'Betty', TIMESTAMP '2023-03-19 11:00:29', 300 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  
SELECT '9999', 'Carol', TIMESTAMP '2023-08-26 01:26:29', 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '8888', 'Carol', TIMESTAMP '2023-08-29 02:26:29', 501 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1234', 'Carol', TIMESTAMP '2023-09-10 03:26:29',  500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '4567', 'Carol', TIMESTAMP '2023-09-11 08:26:29',  501 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2345', 'Carol', TIMESTAMP '2023-09-17 04:26:29', 1001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '3456', 'Carol', TIMESTAMP '2023-09-30 05:26:29', 700 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '5678', 'Carol', TIMESTAMP '2023-10-01 05:26:29', 200 FROM DUAL;
```

I apologize for this, but I need two options to output data :)))

1. Option:
   To display transactions of client `(sender_name)` with total amount sent money more than `(amount)` > 1000 within seven days after the first `transaction_date`. In this case, the result should be: all `Alice`s transactions because the first payment is `03.01` and `within seven days` until `09.01` and her transactions total `amount` during these days is `more than 1000`. And all `Betty`s transactions also have the same logic.For Carol transactions 10.09, 11.09 and 17.09

2.Option:
Is it possible to determine the beginning of the week (starting from Monday) and display client transactions carried out during the week (from Monday to Sunday) with a total amount of more than 1000 (total amount during week)? If yes, than how can be done.

Comment: Haven't you tried anything? You should at least be able to get each person's first transaction. Then you can select from the table again and limit this to the dates from/after (?) first transaction until six days later. Then look at the sums you get. Please show us what you got so far and tell us where you are stuck.

Comment: I don't understand why you pick Carol's transactions of 10.09, 11.09 and 17.09. Her first transaction was on August 26, so the transactions in September are irrelevant.

Comment: Her first transaction on August 26, but total amount within 7 days after this transaction is not more than 1000

Comment: Correct, so Carol must not be in the results, because she doesn't meet the criteria ("amount > 1000 within seven days after the first transaction_date"). The September transactions have nothing to do with this. Why do you mention them? The decision must be the same, with or without the September transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Option 1, you can use analytic functions with a range window to first total the amounts for the past 7 days and then, in a second pass, to count how many rows in the future week have a previously calculated total over 1000 and filter to only those rows:

```sql
SELECT id,
       sender_name,
       transaction_date,
       amount
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         sender_name,
         transaction_date,
         amount,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN previous_weekly_amount > 1000 THEN 1 END) OVER (
             PARTITION BY sender_name
             ORDER BY transaction_date
             RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '0 00:00:00.000000000' DAY TO SECOND PRECEDING
                       AND INTERVAL '6 23:59:59.999999999' DAY TO SECOND FOLLOWING
         ) AS has_weekly_total_over_1000
  FROM   (
    SELECT id,
           sender_name,
           transaction_date,
           amount,
           SUM(amount) OVER (
             PARTITION BY sender_name
             ORDER BY transaction_date
             RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '6 23:59:59.999999999' DAY TO SECOND PRECEDING
                       AND INTERVAL '0 00:00:00.000000000' DAY TO SECOND FOLLOWING
           ) AS previous_weekly_amount
    FROM   transactions
  )
)
WHERE  has_weekly_total_over_1000 > 0;
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

| ID | SENDER_NAME | TRANSACTION_DATE | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | Alice | 2023-01-03 01:26:29.000000000 | 700 |
| 2222 | Alice | 2023-01-05 04:26:29.000000000 | 450 |
| 3333 | Alice | 2023-01-08 18:26:29.000000000 | 1000 |
| 4444 | Alice | 2023-01-09 04:26:29.000000000 | 200 |
| 6666 | Betty | 2023-03-12 15:26:29.000000000 | 845 |
| 7777 | Betty | 2023-03-19 11:00:29.000000000 | 300 |
| 1234 | Carol | 2023-09-10 03:26:29.000000000 | 500 |
| 4567 | Carol | 2023-09-11 08:26:29.000000000 | 501 |
| 2345 | Carol | 2023-09-17 04:26:29.000000000 | 1001 |

---

Option 2, is simpler as you just need to use an analytic function and aggregate by the sender and the ISO week:

```sql
SELECT id,
       sender_name,
       transaction_date,
       amount
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         sender_name,
         transaction_date,
         amount,
         SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY sender_name, TRUNC(transaction_date, 'IW'))
           AS weekly_amount
  FROM   transactions
)
WHERE  weekly_amount > 1000;
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

| ID | SENDER_NAME | TRANSACTION_DATE | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | Alice | 2023-01-03 01:26:29.000000000 | 700 |
| 2222 | Alice | 2023-01-05 04:26:29.000000000 | 450 |
| 3333 | Alice | 2023-01-08 18:26:29.000000000 | 1000 |
| 4567 | Carol | 2023-09-11 08:26:29.000000000 | 501 |
| 2345 | Carol | 2023-09-17 04:26:29.000000000 | 1001 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mLNtVPKL)

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer. https://dbfiddle.uk/4MHJx3iR Just check  please my testing, where I changed calculated amount to >1145. Means Bettys rows will not show. But also one Carols row doesnt display.

Comment: @Saidvali If you want to see what is happening then run the sub-queries and look at the data generated [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Hk-LUn7G). Yes, if you change the limit to `>1145` then that will happen because the excluded rows do not meet that threshold. Carol's `2023-09-10 03:26:29` row is not included because the `2023-09-17 04:26:29` row is outside the 7-day window (by 1 hour and 1 millisecond) so there is only a total amount of 1001 within the 7-day window.

Comment: Great @MT0, thanks a lot

Comment: one more question please. In First option I want to add one more table. `CurrencyRate` table. The fact is in `transactions` table I have one more column `currency`.  The `amount` which we are using now we are getting sum of amount no matter of currency. So, I want first to convert (calculate) rate in, example in USD and then sum them. Example  value of `amount` is 400 and value of `currency` is EUR. I will get the rate of EUR from `CurrencyRate` table and do calculation like 400 / 0.92 and get `amount` 434.8. If `currency` is USD, dont touch. Could you help for this too, please?

Comment: @Saidvali Use a `JOIN` to the table and then multiply or dived by `CurrencyRate` and, if you need to, use a `CASE` expression to check what the currency is (or you could have a USD to USD exchange rate of 1 in the table).

Comment: could you show in code, please?

Comment: @Saidvali If you have a new question then [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). What you are asking is beyond the scope of your initial question and you need to provide a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for both tables; **YOUR** attempt at a solution; and the expected output rather than expecting us to reverse engineer the table from a partial description in a comment.

Comment: check please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77517324/oracle-11g-counting-sum-of-amount-after-converting